# Why zooming in/out doesn't affect the font size (some sites only)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, size, zooming

Sincerely hope someone can provide solution for this.

Normal zooming by holding Ctrl + Scroll (or +/-) is useful but it just doesn't work in certain part of some sites.

For example:

http://www.freemalaysiatoday.com/category/living/2012/04/02/malaysias-top-rock-act-blister/

As you can see, zooming in and out has no effect at all to the text in the comments using facebook account. This problem only happen to Chrome but not IE or firefox.

No matter how large other font becomes, the size of the font (yes, font only) in comments remained unchanged and this is annoying.

Any solution please?

Comment: Google Chrome is not a programming tool, and this is not a programming question.  This is a question about end user use of Chrome, and as such should be asked on a different website, perhaps a Chrome mailing list or forum (after thorough googling of course).

Comment: My bad.
I didn't realize this.
I was reading one question about font issue here and posted my question without reading carefully about this page.
Kindly have my question removed if this is against any rules of this site.
Thank you.

Comment: @Corbin, I think this is a valid place for the question. Would you be saying the same thing if the question was about IE and not Chrome. There are tonnes of question on here like "Why does does not working in [browser]?".

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko The way I interpret this question, he is not the owner of the site.  He is just an end user trying to get Chrome to zoom as he wishes.  That is not related to programming, a programming tool, or the field of professional programming at all.  That is an end user question.  Like asking how to make something bold in Microsoft Word.  If the site is, however his, then yes, I am mistaken and it is on topic.

Comment: Corbin, Google is not a programming tool but abraham's problem sould be solved with a programmed script :)

Comment: @Corbin, I think you are over-critical.  I think the question is useful in terms of programming.  The OP refers to the site only for examples, which doesn't rule out the possibility he was trying to write a webpage, and met the issue, while he was not happy to publish his own website, therefore referred a webpage of someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Look at:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104083

It can be achieved with the css rule `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`.

If one wants to disable it, the link also contains a solution in step 8, using an extension CSS rules are inserted in all pages which override this